# Entity Framework Activity Callbacks

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Does Entity Framework (6+) have activity callback mechanisms as I would like to bind some functions to know what entity framework is doing. Such as "Issueing Query" or "Downloading from SQL Server" etc. This could be similar to the Log functionality where you can bind an action to whenever it logs debug information. If it does exist im not exactly sure of what that feature is called or how I need to implement it into my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IDbCommandInterceptor` to log all the activities performed by your entity framework context. You can implement it like this:

**EFCommandInterceptor.cs**

```
class EFCommandInterceptor: IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void NonQueryExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("NonQueryExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("NonQueryExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync,  command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ReaderExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ReaderExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ScalarExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ScalarExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    private void LogInfo(string command, string commandText)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Intercepted on: {0} :- {1} ", command, commandText);
    }
}
```

then configure it in your config file

```
<entityFramework>
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor type="EF6DBFirstTutorials.EFCommandInterceptor, EF6DBFirstTutorials">
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>
</entityFramework>
```

Please check [this page](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/database-command-interception.aspx) for more details.

Comment: After looking at this there are numourous other Interceptors of base interface IDbInterceptor

Comment: Yes, there are `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor`, `IDbConfigurationInterceptor`, `IDbConnectionInterceptor` to name others. Which ones to use depends upon what operations you want to log in your application.